# Run a media in android for x seconds

Tags: android, loops

I have a tune in my android app. I have added a feature that if user selects a time then the tune will repeat until the time ends. I have also added the feature of infinite time but when I run my app goes in ANR (not responding) mode.

```
if(tinydb.getString("timer").equals("infinity"))
      {
        boolean valid = true;  //Here i want to play the tune for infinite time 
        while(valid) 
          {
           water_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
           water_player.start();
           }
        }
 else
   {
     while(!timerText.equals("0h: 0m: 1s")) //Here i want to play the tune until the timer gets zero
     {
      water_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
      water_player.start();
     }
```

Comment: do you release the media player resources after playing?

Comment: no i didn't but at some instances i stop it

Comment: you should always release resources when not required also check if there are any blocking calls that block ui.

Comment: i did that but still my app gets hang

Comment: you have to do some profile use android studio profiler and check what is blocking the ui thread. the code above does not help much other than people making guess.

Comment: i never used android studio profiler

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler. read the docs and follow it.

Comment: Your code is not giving any hint how you are managing time specified.you better use a countdowntimer for playing ypur audio file for x seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [setLooping](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setLooping(boolean)) for the first case

and for the second case

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   water_player.stop();
   }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000); //your time in millisecond
```

with your code :

```
if(tinydb.getString("timer").equals("infinity"))
  {
       water_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
       water_player.setLooping(true);
       water_player.start();          
    }
else
{
  water_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
  water_player.start();
  final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      water_player.stop();
    }
  };
  handler.postDelayed(r, 1000); //your time in millisecond
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use countdownTimer to complete your goal in which you can set countdown timer till x seconds manually. when countdown finish process it will go to finish method and execute finish method code

```
CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mp_xmPlayer2.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //code fire after finish
               mp_xmPlayer2.stop();
        }
        };cntr_aCounter.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 cases, use a boolean.

```
boolean infinitely;
if(infinitely == true){
    water_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
    water_player.start();
}
else {
    water_player = new MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
    water_player.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        water_player.stop();
    }

                        }
                        , 2000);
```

The handler method will be executed when 2sec passed. (put your own desired time).